# What's the use of the expected fisher information matrix over the hessian in the Newton Raphson approach to finding the MLE?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, extreme-value, fisher-information

This may be a naive question, but I'm looking at the Newton Raphson iterative approach ( i.e. using the formula $\boldsymbol{\theta }^{(j+1)} = \boldsymbol{\theta }^{(j)} + \textrm{Hess}_{-\ell}(\boldsymbol{\theta }^{(j)})^{-1} \nabla \ell(\boldsymbol{\theta }^{(j)})$ until you have convergence) to finding the MLE, and a lot of papers suggest using the (expected) fisher information matrix instead of the hessian of the negated log-likelihood (in particular I'm looking at the GEV distribution).

What's the point in this? Is it easier somehow?

Comment: Now, most of the time the convergence speed will be the same, and the computational burden also. It’s called Fisher scoring, and I think Fisher invented it without prior knowledge of Newton’s method. The same phenomenon occurs with various numerical methods in statistics, some of then much more recent — if you write down carefully the iterated weighted least squares algorithm used for fitting generalized linear models, you’ll see that it boils down to Newton's method. It's remarkably hard to find a textbook in which this is done.

Comment: Besides the problem of MLE, both the Hessian and the Expected
information matrix can be used for approximate inference. In
[Statistical Models](http://statwww.epfl.ch/davison/SM) sec. 4.4,
A.C Davison argues that the Hessian provides a better
approximation. In an experimentation on the GPD, I found that it was
indeed the case. The approximate sd for the estimated shape $\widehat{\xi}$ takes larger values and the corresponding $t$ ratio
takes is much more normal with the Hessian than it is with the
observed information matrix. I would however encourage using the exact hessian.